# How to visualize several parameters in a barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am trying to make a graph, were I have amount up the y-axis (numeric), Office place (categorical) on the x= axis, sorted in regions (categorical)...
What I have tried to do:

```
My_df %>%
  filter(Context == "Humanitarian") %>%
  ggplot(aes(Office_abb, Award_USD)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(color=Region, fill = Region)) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") + 
  ggtitle("Overview of office amount pr. region")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

My error message on the above script is: 
Error: stat_bin() must not be used with a y aesthetic.

I wold like it to be in a stacked diagram, or dodged - but when I tried to add

```
geom_bar(position = "dodge2")
```

into the equation, it didn't work either

It did however work with **geom_point** - but that is not the type of visualization that I wish for.

With that i am kind of lost on what to do - I hope that someone can help me move on from here! :-)

Comment: Sounds like you need `geom_col` (or `stat = "identity"` in `geom_bar`).

Comment: Yes, a `geom_bar` is a special type which actually counts the number of observations in each group. Here you want to plot the actual values, so do as the above suggests

Comment: You guys are great!! - thank you so much for the help!